# Make app background to foreground in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, background

I am trying to make my app alive. And bring it to foreground from background.

But this is not happening.

I have used operURL concept for achieving in application will enter background method but it is not helping me out.

I have also attempted [UIApplication specialLaunchApp:@"com.companyname.appname"];,
but this is also not working.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing you can do to this is having a background app that uses the background local notifications API to display a message to the user that prompts them to re-open the app.

Apps can **not** promote themselves to the foreground without user action of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Only the user should be able to bring your app to the foreground.